# Cannot write in applicationHost.cofig file of IIS

Tags: file, iis, permissions, applicationhost

I am experimenting this problem deleting an IP restriction on IIS:

[image: IIS write file error]

I have given all permissions to the user but it did not resolve the problem, I also try to free some space on disk without any result, is there anything that I can try to solve it, this is happening since a month ago, thanks beforehand for any help.

Comment: Does user have admin access?

Comment: yes, it does. I made sure that the user had admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the file using notepad launched from an admin command prompt.

1. Open a cmd prompt by right clicking it, select 'run as administrator'.
2. At the cmd prompt type

   notepad c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config

Comment: It was very curious when i tryed, because I could do it, but that was not the solution, thanks for the help, I colud solve it, I only reboot the server and IIS works again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the log server finish in an invalid state because of the memory was full time ago, so once the memory was empty I rebooted the server and everything works perfectly.